# Use multiple Dask schedulers

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

We're using Dask to distribute the computation tasks to multiple servers. There is 1 dask-scheduler and 5 dask-worker servers. My question is: is there a way so that multiple dask-schedulers can be used? I'm asking this because single dask-scheduler can't avoid single point of failure, and sometimes, if the requests are in a very high volume, the single-scheduler could be a bottleneck of the performance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A dask cluster runs with a single scheduler, and overhead due to assigning tasks can indeed be a bottleneck in some circumstances.

To answer your specific question, yes you can connect to separate schedulers from the same python process/session, if you wish: each call to `Client()` can point to a different address. Whether that is useful for some sort of load balancing is hard to say - the clusters will not know about each other and not share any resources.